# I'm having trouble looping through an array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I'm using MyJSON to create a store for my data and im having trouble looping through it

i've tried .map(), .forEach but i cannot for the life of me, map over the array of objects.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

the JSON store looks like this

```
const Leaderboard = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchScores();
    },[]);

    const renderList = () => {
        props.scores.map(item => {
            return <LeaderboardItem name={item.name} data={item.date} />
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="leaderboard">
            <h1 className='leaderboard__header'> Leaderboard</h1>
            {renderList()}
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        scores: state.scores
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchScores })(Leaderboard);
```

I'm able to fetch the data, add it to my reducers. When i console.log my props i get this

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "ryan", score: 3, date: 1564079441826, id: 1}
1: {name: "ryan", score: 0, date: 1564080251976, id: 2}
2: {name: "ryan", score: 4, date: 1564080621616, id: 3}
3: {name: "ryan", score: 1, date: 1564088666800, id: 4}
4: {name: "ryan", score: 8, date: 1564088919233, id: 5}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

shouldn't I be able to map over the array and return each object?

```
      10 | },[]);
      11 | 
      12 | const renderList = () => {
    > 13 |     props.scores.map(item => console.log(item))
         | ^  14 | }
      15 | 
      16 | return (
```

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_SCORES:
        return { ...state, ...action.payload }
    default:
        return state;
};
```

};

images :

[Redux-dev-tools-image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6vl1.png)

[Redux-dev-tools-image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn8Qr.png)

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buypv.png)

Comment: How are you connecting the component? you are not passing the array correctly. You also aren't returning jsx in the `renderList`

Comment: Please add more code. The error indicates that `props.scores` does not contain anything

Comment: updated post to show my component! 

when I console.log(state.scores) in my mapStateToProps it shows that it contains the array of objects

Comment: I can also see through redux-dev tools that my scores reducers is return the same scores array with objects inside it

Comment: please post your reducer code. Is the state something like `{ scores: [] }`? you would need to connect it like `state.scores.scores`. `state.scores` is the whole scores reducer, if your list is a key on that object you need to reference it. Since it's saying undefined, make sure that `scores` is the key in `combineReducers`

Comment: yea, so you need to connect with `return { scores: state.scores.scores }`

Comment: how are you combining the reducers? in your `mapStateToProps` can you `console.log(state)` to see what data you have?

Comment: @niinjano your console.log is showing undefined then the array. I updated the reducer to keep an array datatype so you keep things consistent.

Answer (score 1):

to render a list of items [**you need to actually return JSX in your map**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ud1xl)

```
const renderList = () => {
  props.scores.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>)
}
```

You should [**read up on best practices**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for rendering lists of elements in react.

### Edit

Since `scores` is undefined, you need to make sure that you are referencing things correctly.

Is `scores` the key defined in `combineReducers`? aka something like `combineReducers({scores: scoresReducer})`

Update your reducer to store what you want to store all the time. dont change the datatypes

```
const defaultState = {
  scores: []
}
export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_SCORES:
        return { ...state, scores: ...action.payload }
    default:
        return state;
  };
}
```

this assumes `action.payload` is an array of scores, adjust accordingly if its not

Comment: i was actually originally returning this, but was getting TypeError: props.scores.map is not a function                                                                  
const renderList = () => {
        props.scores.map(item => {
            return <LeaderboardItem name={item.name} data={item.date} />
        })
    }

Comment: I see your update, how are you updating the data in your reducer? is `state.scores` an array? or maybe its an object with the `scores` array inside?

Comment: i've added two images of the redux dev tools & and my code for my reducer. its definietly state.scores.scores because when i console.log that, it logs the array directly.

Comment: I updated it to score.score, but im still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. could the culprit be that its trying to map the array before the state has been retrieved from the store?

Comment: Well, you should define a default value in your state so you aren't dealing with different data types

Comment: thank you so much!! this fixed it! I had the default value set to an object instead of an array!

Comment: Great! glad that worked out! Its hard to answer a redux question issue because it could be how you `connect` it, or how the `reducer` is defined, or how you `combineReducers`... etc haha. But we got there :)

Answer (score 0):

`map` creates another array as a transformation of the original array. You are simply `console.log`'ing over each item which would be a use for `forEach` and not `map`.

The return value of a `console.log` is `undefined` and probably causing problems while rendering an array of `[undefined, undefined, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider this:

```
        props.scores && props.scores.map(item => {
            return <LeaderboardItem name={item.name} data={item.date} />
        })
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't crash, could you tell me what the extra props.scores && does?

Comment: The possible scenario is, when you run `props.fetchScores()` it doesnt really fetch data immediatly, thus, scores might be still undefined from it's source, until the fetch set's it's value, a possible other fix is to give `props.scores` a default value `Array[]`